# p5.js Instance Mode: How to access the instance variables from inside a class

Tags: javascript, webpack, p5.js

I'm having trouble using p5js in instance mode. I split my code into multiple files for easier maintenance, separating classes from the main sketch file.

Inside the classes i need access to variables declared in the main sketch but i get `undefined` when i inject the sketch object into the class.

Ideally i would like to have access to ANY variables declared in the main sketch file. Is it possible/recommended?

Here is a minimum case example of what i'm trying to achieve:

index.js

```
import p5 from "p5"
import TestClass from "./_testClass";

let sketch = new p5( (p) => {
    let myColor = 75;

    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(1000,1000);
        let t = new TestClass(100,100)
        t.render(p)
    }
}, "p5");
```

_testClass.js

```
export default class TestClass {
    constructor(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    render(p) {
        p.rect(this.x, this.y, 50, 50); // i get a square on the canvas: p.rect() is recognized
        console.log(p.myColor); // undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't add properties to libraries I don't own. Why do you want to do this? Seems like a likely [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variables that you want to be available within the `TestClass`'s `render()` function either need to be 1) passed to the `TestClass` constructor, 2) passed to the render function, 3) declared/assigned on/to the `p5` instance, or 4) declared globally.

For instance mode sketches it is not uncommon to add things to the `p5` instance:

```js
import p5 from "p5"
import TestClass from "./_testClass";

let sketch = new p5((p) => {
    // let myColor = 75;
    p.myColor = 75;

    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(1000,1000);
        let t = new TestClass(100,100)
        t.render(p)
    }
}, "p5");
```

However, I think it would be better OOP practice to pass this to your `TestClass` constructor:

```
import p5 from "p5"
import TestClass from "./_testClass";

let sketch = new p5((p) => {
    let myColor = 75;

    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(1000, 1000);
        let t = new TestClass(100, 100, myColor)
        t.render(p)
    }
}, "p5");

export default class TestClass {
    constructor(x, y, rectColor) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.rectColor = rectColor;
    }
    
    render(p) {
        console.log(this.rectColor);
        p.fill(this.rectColor);
        p.rect(this.x, this.y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding to the `p5` instance feels cleaner when i have a bunch to reference in the class. Also in many cases i already need to inject `p` to the classes, so it would be available anyway. Is it considered a bad practice? Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I think it is mostly a subjective question, but there are downsides: 1) When assigning things to the p5 instance you have be careful to avoid name collisions, both with existing p5.js functions and with other parts of your code that might do the same thing. 2) There's a risk of a future version of p5.js introducing a name collision. 3) It may make your code harder to read in the future because you may be uncertain where a particular value came from.